# Integrate Redis server on Siteground hosted website

Tags: php, redis, web-hosting

I developed a website using php and redis in my pc offline and now I want to host it on siteground. But I can't really install the redis-cli software there like I did in my pc right!? So how do I really integrate a redis server on siteground?

I realize my question is too open. But I really tried searching everything on the internet and unfortunately found nothing related. Any help or resource is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

first, if you had a redis database external than siteground, can try install a redis client via composer as this https://github.com/nrk/predis